# How can I list the devices connected to my WiFi network using VB6 or BAT/CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vb6, wifi

I am making a program to list all the devices who are connected to my Wi-Fi network so that I can see if anyone else is connected.

I have found a code for CMD - **net view** but it lists only the computers connected to my Wi-Fi but not the mobile devices. Is there any other command to list mobile devices connected to my Wi-Fi using CMD.

Comment: If this is a small network, then you could look at what the wireless router or access point reports a connections. It would take some work to script that into a command line tool, but the information is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an external tool called  : **[Wireless Network Watcher](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_watcher.html)**

[image]

**Description :**

> Wireless Network Watcher is a small utility that scans your wireless
>   network and displays the list of all computers and devices that are
>   currently connected to your network. For every computer or device that
>   is connected to your network, the following information is displayed:
>   IP address, MAC address, the company that manufactured the network
>   card, and optionally the computer name. You can also export the
>   connected devices list into html/xml/csv/text file, or copy the list
>   to the clipboard and then paste into Excel or other spreadsheet
>   application.

And you can create a batch file to save the result with HTML like this :

```
@echo off
WNetWatcher.exe /shtml "WNetWatcher.html" 
Start "" "WNetWatcher.html"
```

***Command-Line Options :***

> ***/cfg***      Start Wireless Network Watcher with the specified 
>   configuration file. For example: WNetWatcher.exe /cfg
>   "c:\config\wnw.cfg" WNetWatcher.exe /cfg "%AppData%\WNetWatcher.cfg"
>
> ***/stext***    Scan your network, and save the network devices
>   list into a regular text file.
>
> ***/stab***     Scan your network,
>   and save the network devices list into a tab-delimited text file.
>
> ***/scomma***   Scan your network, and save the network devices
>   list into a comma-delimited text file (csv).
>
> ***/stabular***     Scan your network, and save the network devices 
>   list into a tabular text file.
>
> ***/shtml***    Scan your network, and save the network devices
>   list into HTML file (Horizontal).
>
> ***/sverhtml***      Scan your network, and save the network
>   devices    list into HTML file (Vertical).
>
> ***/sxml***     Scan your network, and save the network devices
>   list into XML file.

Comment: @GAD3R You are welcome.And i wish a long life for Tunisian people like you bro ;)