# Get a List of available Wireless Networks using VBA

Tags: vba

In excel I am trying to get a list of all available wireless connections and list them in an excel spreadsheet.  I have gone through and I was able to find my wireless adapter using the following code, but I am wanting to see all available connections from that adapter and I do not know where to go from here:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject( _
    "winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colNetCards = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration ")

For Each objNetCard In colNetCards
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = objNetCard.Description
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        If 0 < InStr(objNetCard.Description, "Wireless") Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Found It!!!"
        Else
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Not Found"
        End If
```

I do not know if I am on the right track or maybe I am going in the wrong direction, but any help would be appreciated... Thank You

To clarify in the end my desired list would show available SSIDs that I could essentially connect to if I wanted to.

Comment: I think the query you want is `SELECT * FROM MSNdis_80211_ServiceSetIdentifier`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list the devices connected to my WiFi network using VB6 or BAT/CMD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698037/how-can-i-list-the-devices-connected-to-my-wifi-network-using-vb6-or-bat-cmd)

Comment: @GAD3R - The "duplicate" doesn't have a real answer - I'm guessing that using an external tool isn't what the OP is after.

Comment: using that query I should get an array of objects that would be related to the available networks?  Should I be able to use for each to iterate through them then?

Comment: See [ACCESS VBA - Obtain Wireless Network Name (Connected)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36414339/4088852).  Note that you'll need to take the `WHERE active=true` off the end of the query.  Also note that I *still* don't have any combination of Windows and wireless to test it with.

Comment: when I am executing that code with the WHERE active=true removed I am getting an empty item list... I currently have 2 wireless networks where I am at. How did you put the code inline as if it were a code block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to use the netsh commands and was able to get the results that I wanted from the following code...

```
Dim strNetwork As String
strNetwork = ShellRun("netsh wlan show network")

Public Function ShellRun(sCmd As String) As String

    'Run a shell command, returning the output as a string'
    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    'run command'
    Dim oExec As Object
    Dim oOutput As Object
    Set oExec = oShell.Exec(sCmd)
    Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut

    'handle the results as they are written to and read from the StdOut object'
    Dim s As String
    Dim sLine As String
    While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
        sLine = oOutput.ReadLine
        If sLine <> "" Then s = s & sLine & vbCrLf
    Wend

    ShellRun = s

End Function
```

Hopefully this helps anyone in the future that is trying to do come up with a solution for something like this.